# How do i get last index of json array in dust js template

Tags: arrays, dust.js

I have json data like

```
{
"itinerary": {
    "carrier": "9W",
    "refundable": false,
    "dept": {
        "flightList": [
            {
                "from": {
                    "date": "200713",
                    "code": "KTM",
                    "terminal": null,
                    "time": "1430"
                }
            },
            {
                "from": {
                    "date": "210713",
                    "code": "BOM",
                    "terminal": "1B",
                    "time": "0440"
                }
            },
            {
                "from": {
                    "date": "210713",
                    "code": "AMD",
                    "terminal": null,
                    "time": "1420"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}
Now i want to display 'KTM' and 'AMD' from json which is first and last array of itinerary.dept.flightList
Now I could get first index like this {itinerary.dept.flightList[0].from.code} but i couldn't get last one. 
Could anyone help me to get last index of itinerary.dept.flightList without using loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using the `{@if}`, `{$idx}`, and `{$len}` helpers.

```
{#itinerary.dept.flightList}
    {@if cond="{$idx} == 0 || {$idx} == ({$len} - 1)"}
        {from.code}
    {/if}
{/itinerary.dept.flightList}
```

You can see a working example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jamsyoung/Ucpf5/

More information is also available at:

- [$idx and $len in a dust.js conditional statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910070/idx-and-len-in-a-dust-js-conditional-statement)
- https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial (search for idx and len)

Answer (score 1):

It will be length of the array minus 1.

```
itinerary.dept.flightList[itinerary.dept.flightList.length-1].from.code
```

Comment: Thanx Orangepill, But i tried this before this code didn't worked. I tried like {itinerary.dept.flightList[itinerary.dept.flightList.length-1].to.code}  to get 'AMD' from that json but this didn't worked. any other way to get it ?

Comment: @user1632223 Sorry I missed the flightList level of the composed object... updated answer to show usave to get the from code for the last element in the supplied example

Comment: @user1632223 I updated again after testing the code... should be on the money now.

Comment: I tried this code " itinerary.dept.flightList[itinerary.dept.flightList.length-1].from.code "before i post this question, this code didn't worked so i post this question. Does it depend on dust version currently i am using dust-full-1.2.0.js ?

Comment: I'm answering based on how you access a property with this composition for javascript in general. The posted example show how to get the property from the json object posted on the question. Nothing specific to dust.

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to mention dust js template in my comments. But i have mention it in my question. Anyway thank you for your answer. So now do you have any solution for this in dust js.

Comment: @user1632223 you may have to right a custom helper for this unfortunately :(